# how to combine indirect and HLOOKUP in formula excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I try to combine hlookup with indirect to obtain a value of array

```
sheet1 :
 In the cell  A5, I have the value : [file1.xlsx]sheet34!
In the cell A6, I have the value : $A$1:$Z$100
```

sheet2 :

I did :

```
=HLOOKUP(H$3;(INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!A5"));INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!A6");LIGNE();0)
```

ps:  in A1 of sheet2, it is a cell where I wrote sheet1

But it doesn't work, and I tried too much things, that I have no idea about how it could work

Thanks for reading me

Comment: Looks to me like you're constructing your references the wrong way round. Do `INDIRECT("'"&A5&"'!A1"))` and `INDIRECT("'"&A6&"'!A1")` work any better?

Comment: thanks for answering me, but no it was not my problem, my problem is to combine hlookup with indirect of sheet1 for cell A5 and A6

Comment: Your `HLOOKUP` will only work if all its parameters are valid. In separate cells, check whether `INDIRECT` is giving the output you expect.

Comment: `=HLOOKUP(H$3;INDIRECT("'"&A5&"'!"&A6);LIGNE();0)`